# migrating from google apps standard mail to yahoo small business mail (not a programming question)

Tags: google-apps

Our Company wishes to transfer its mail from google apps standard to Yahoo small business mail, how to do that seamlessly.

Thanks and regards

Comment: i got the call from yahoo guy and he is directing us. so i am posting this as closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i contacted yahoo support and it is been on the process , worth a blog experience.